# How to get the State or Province using Geocoder Php

Tags: laravel, geocoding, geocoder

I'm wanting to reverse geocode coordinate to get the address using Geocoder-php. I'm able to get the Address Collection using `$geo = app('geocoder')->reverse($lat, $lng)->get()`.

According to [these docs found on github](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/3.x/README.md) for Geocoder-php you can retrieve the properties form the collection, such as street name by using `$geo->getStreetName()`, the city by using `$geo->getCity()`, the country by using `$geo->getCountry()`, etc, but there are no methods for returning the State or Province.

How do I grab the state or province from the collection?

I can see the province when I use `$geo->getAdminLevels()->get()`. Which returns

```
AdminLevelCollection {#900 ▼
  -adminLevels: array:2 [▼
    1 => AdminLevel {#901 ▼
      -level: 1
      -name: "Saskatchewan"
      -code: "SK"
    }
    2 => AdminLevel {#902 ▼
      -level: 2
      -name: "Division No. 16"
      -code: "Division No. 16"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am unable to grab the province (Saskatchewan).

(I am using [Laravel Geocoder](http://geocoder-php.org/GeocoderLaravel/) for a Laravel project.)

EDIT:

`$geo->getAdminLevels()->get(1)` give me this

```
AdminLevel {#690 ▼
  -level: 1
  -name: "Saskatchewan"
  -code: "SK"
}
```

But `$geo->getAdminLevels()->get(1)->name;` give me this error

```
Undefined property: Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps\Model\GoogleAddress::$getAdminLevels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to call it this way;

```
$geo->getAdminLevels()->get(1)->getName();
```

`get()` in this context takes a value of the index you wish to return.

You might want to check that the `getAdminLevels()` and `get(1)` return values if they may sometimes return nulls. You can do this by implementing something like `!empty($geo->getAdminLevels())`

Comment: If that doesn't work; it may be $geo->getAdminLevels()->adminLevels->get();

Comment: `$geo->getAdminLevels()->get();` throws an error`Too few arguments to function Geocoder\Model\AdminLevelCollection::get(), 0 passed in /path/to/my/Controller.php exactly 1 expected`

and `$geo->getAdminLevels()->adminLevels->get();` throws an error `Cannot access private property Geocoder\Model\AdminLevelCollection::$adminLevels`

Comment: Try $geo->getAdminLevels()->get(1); Does this give you anything? If it does try $geo->getAdminLevels->get(1)->name;

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Still getting an error. Take a look at my updated question.

Comment: OK name is a private property on the AdminLevel class - you'll need to do $geo->getAdminLevels->get(1)->getName(); If that works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Error again `Undefined property: Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps\Model\GoogleAddress::$getAdminLevels` :(

Comment: Can you confirm you're calling this: $geo->getAdminLevels()->get(1)->getName(); also are you using the same lat, lng each time?

Comment: Hey that did it! `$geo->getAdminLevels()->get(1)->getName()` works! Please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do
`$geo->getAdminLevels()->get()->adminLevels[0]->name` or `$geo->getAdminLevels()->get()->adminLevels[1]->name`

Comment: Both throws an error `Too few arguments to function Geocoder\Model\AdminLevelCollection::get(), 0 passed in /path/to/my/Controller.php exactly 1 expected`